GitHub API Call for Updated Column from Branches Page
The "Branches" page of a GitHub repo has an "Updated" column. Is there a way to use the GitHub API (REST or GraphQL) to access the actor in that column for a given branch, or to access all the branches that have a given actor in that column?

This is not necessarily the same as the actor that authored or committed the branch's head commit; It's more like the actor who "pushed" the branch's head commit, where that "push" could have also been simply creating the branch through the UI or API. In fact, my use case specifically exists within the edge case where the pusher and the committer differ (so this isn't a duplicate of this answer).
I see the GitHub GraphQL schema specifies a Push object with a pusher field, but I don't see it referenced anywhere else in the schema so I'm not sure how to access it.
